# What is the best spot to strike a tennis ball?

Tags: equipment, tennis, technique, racket

As seen in the image below, there are several "sweet spots" on a tennis racket.

Before seing this picture, I always strived to hit the ball in the center of the racket, which seem to feel the nicest, however after seeing this diagram, and practicing bouncing the ball onto the racket in various positions, It seems the yellow area shown below does have more rebound.

Therefore, I ask the question, is it better to master  striking the ball in the center of the racket or the yellow spot shown in the picture below, or somewhere else entirely, for optimum performance?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no correct reply always true for this question, but I **bolted the most one** according to your image.

Anyway you can use this hint to understand the meaning of the points:

- Point 1 is the Center of Percussion (COP in your image) and offers the least amount of initial shock to the hand when struck. Shock is generally accepted as being potentially most harmful to player's arms.
- Point 2 is the Nodal Point (Node in your image) and produces the least amount of vibration when struck. Frame vibration is what players feel after ball contact in certain more flexible rackets.
- **Point 3 is the area of Maximum Coefficient of Restitution**, or a racket's power (**Best bouce in your image**) and the exact position depend on several factors (racket's weight, balance, length, headsize and string tension).

[Here](https://www.comsol.com/blogs/the-physics-of-tennis-racket-sweet-spots/) and also [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2577483/) you can find a deep explanation of this topics with physics details

Comment: Thanks, where do professional tennis players try to hit?  At least shock, or most power?

Comment: @Mew In my opinion there is no absolutely true answer to this question, I think it depends on the player and the type of shot

Answer (score 2):

There is no right or optimal place to hit a ball on the tennis racket that applies to everyone. Everyone plays differently and looks to get a different type of result out of each shot.

I'm definitely no expert on the physics of tennis, but I can tell you from experience, where on your racket you should aim to hit the ball.

The part labeled **Node**, is probably the best for when you your trying to roll a nice spin ball off your racket.

The part labeled **COP**, is the opposite, and should be used when hitting a slice ball.

However, while the bottom area of the racket (labeled **Best Bounce** in your image), is usually used for a flat ball because the ball doesn't need much room to roll on your racket, I would stay away from it in many cases. If you're a player who enjoys smacking that ball when you're on the offensive, then go ahead. But it's not always the best for **Touch**. That area of the racket is usually unpredictable and isn't optimal for a volley or drop shot.

When hitting a serve, just anywhere in the middle of the racket is fine. It all really depends on where you're placing it anyways.

In the end, don't try to base your tennis off of science and physics. It can only help so much, and feel is the best way to truly learn. Besides, nobody is perfect and can hit those exact areas on the racket every time. I would just try to drill as much as possible, until you develop your own areas for hitting the ball.